# jquery ui spinner not showing correctly in chrome safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, user-interface, safari, spinner

I'm using the jquery ui spinner just as they specify. I have an input of type number and the only thing I changed is setting the size to 1. In firefox it looks as it should, like this:[image]
But in safari and chrome it looks like this: [image]. It becomes un-resized and I'm not sure why there are additional arrows (they work too). All I did to set these up was move over the css and js files from jquery ui and in my js I do the following on my number input: `$('#idOfNumberInput').spinner();`

Any ideas why it isn't showing correctly in chrome or safari and how I could fix it?

Comment: maybe if you can update the images this question would look better :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. I fixed the resizing bye setting the width of my input box in the css rather than using the size attribute. I also did not know that a lot of browsers have a native spinner for input's of type="number" but apparently firefox doesn't (or at least not my version). I fixed the issue by using the jquery spinner widget on an input of type="text" instead.

Comment: this answer is very useful :) changing the input type="number" to "text" works :D thx